# Simple examples with 2 dimensional wchar_t string array

Tags: c++, c

Can somebody explain why next code output 26 timez 'Z' instead range from 'A' to 'Z', and how can I output this array correct. Look at code:

```
wchar_t *allDrvs[26];
    int count = 0;
     for (int n=0; n<26; n++)
     {
         wchar_t t[] = {L'A' + n, '\0'}; 
         allDrvs[n] = t;
         count++;
     }
     int j;
     for(j = 0; j < count; j++)
     {
        std::wcout << allDrvs[j] << std::endl;
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem (at least one) is:

```
{
     wchar_t t[] = {L'A' + n, '\0'}; 
     allDrvs[n] = t;  //allDrvs points to t
     count++;         
 }   //t is deallocated here
     //allDrvs[n] is a dangling pointer
```

So, short answer - undefined behavior on the line `std::wcout << allDrvs[j]`.

To get a correct output - there's a <del>crappy</del> ugly version involving dynamic allocation and copying between arrays.

Then there's the correct version of using a `std::vector<std::wstring> >`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `t[]` is on the stack; it only exists for one iteration of the loop at a time, and the next iteration appears to be reusing that space - not a behaviour that's required, but this seems to be what's happening based on your results. If you examine `allDrvs[]` with a debugger after the first loop completes, you'll probably see all the pointers point to the same memory location.

There's a variety of ways you could solve this. You can allocate a new `t` on the heap for each loop iteration (and delete them afterwards). You could do `wchar_t allDrvs[26][2];` instead of `wchar_t *allDrvs[26]`, and copy the contents of `t` over each iteration. You could display `t` right away in the first loop, instead of doing it later. You could use `std::vector` and `std::wstring` to manage things for you, instead of using arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior. Your `t` has automatic storage duration, so as soon as you exit the upper loop, it ceases to exist. Your `allDrvs` contains 26 pointers to objects that have been destroyed by the time you use them in the second loop.

As it happens, it looks like (under the circumstances you're running it, with the compiler you're using, etc.) what's happening is that it's re-using the same storage space for `t` at ever iteration of the loop, and when you use `allDrvs` in the second loop, that storage hasn't been overwritten, so you have 26 pointers to the same data.

Since you're using C++ anyway, I'd advise using `std::wstring` and probably `std::vector` instead -- for example, something on this general order:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> allDrvs;

for (char i=L'A'; i<L'Z'; i++)
     allDrvs.push_back(std::wstring(i));
```

Technically, this isn't entirely portable -- it depends on `'A' .. 'Z'` being contiguous, which isn't true with all character sets, IBM's EBCDIC being the obvious exception. Even in that case, it'll produce all the right outputs, but it'll also include a few additional items you didn't really want.

Nonetheless, the original depended on `'A'..'Z'` being contiguous, and the code looks like it's probably intended for Windows anyway, so that's probably not really a big concern.